# Undefined add_column in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I am trying to run a migration in Rails 3, I wish to add a column to a table, the code looks like this:

```
class AddConstAdr < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table: constants do |t|
      t.add_column :home_address, :string
    end
  end
end
```

When I do `rake db:migrate` I get an error saying undefined method 'add_column'. I am confused as to why this is happening, can anyone help?

Comment: Is `change_table: constants` a typo that should be `change_table :constants`?

Comment: Artiom: you should accept answers if they helped you. Aside from rewarding people who spent their time to help you, this also helps future visitors to find correct answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two different ways of doing a migration. You probably want this:

```
def change
  change_table :constants do |t|
    t.string :home_address
  end
end
```

or this:

```
def change
  add_column :constants, :home_address, :string
end
```

Both forms should do the same thing: add a `home_address` string column to the `constants` table.

I'm also assuming that your `change_table: constants` is just a typo that should have been `change_table :constants`.

Further information may be found in the [Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should do as below:

```
def change
  add_column :constants, :home_address, :string
end
```